# Reading from a Java InputStream generated by a shell script happens in batches

Tags: java, shell, inputstream, bufferedreader, processbuilder

I am trying to orchestrate Python scripts on a Raspberry Pi through a Java program. I have some Python code with an infinite loop inside that reads the distance from an ultrasonic sensor and outputs it to the console. The Java code calls this as a shell process and then reads the OutputStream the process. The problem I am experiencing is that the data arrives in large batches. Instead of me getting a new value every time the Python script outputs to the console, I get new data every 10 seconds or so. This is problematic because I am trying to display the data on a web dashboard in near-realtime.

The diagram would look like the following:

```
DistanceController
    |--getDistance(public)
    |--getBufferSize(public)
    |--buffer(private)
    |--DistanceThread(private)
            |--bufferReference (private)
            |--PythonScriptProcess
```

The Java code is the following:

This is a wrapper class that instantiates a new thread (separate class) to read from the output stream of the Python script.

```
public class DistanceController {
    private DistanceThread distanceThread;
    private Thread t;
    private LinkedList<DistanceVT>  buffer = new LinkedList<DistanceVT>();

    public DistanceController()
    {            
        t = new Thread(distanceThread);
        t.start();
    }

    public DistanceVT getDistance() {
        return buffer.getLast();
    }
}
```

This is the thread that reads the distance, the idea is for it to be non-blocking.

```
public class DistanceThread implements Runnable {
private LinkedList<DistanceVT> buffer;
private String[] args = new String[]{"python", "./run-scripts/distance.py"};

public DistanceThread(LinkedList<DistanceVT> list) {buffer = list;}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            final Process p = pb.start();
            while (true) {
                InputStream s = p.getInputStream();
                final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s));
                while (((line = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
                    buffer.add(parseDistance(line));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle errors
        }
    }
}
```

And the Python code looks like so (a slightly modified version of the simplest distance measurement code):

```
import time
import datetime
from random import randint

def measure_distance():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return randint(10,15)

while True:
    distance = measure_distance()
    print ("%s,%s" % (datetime.datetime.now(),distance))
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code required to the absolute minimum to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Of course Jim, I will edit my original question?

Comment: The process producing the output is buffering it. Nothing you can do about that in the Java code. Fix the Python code. NB No thread reading from a `Reader` or `InputStream` can possibly be non-blocking. It is also entirely unclear why the buffering matters, when your reading thread just accumulates the output in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you all for your help. EJP solved the buffering problem- adding a sys.stdout.flush() to the Python code resolved the problem.

As to the other questions- you are right. What I meant is that since I am reading on a separate thread, the main thread of the program can carry on doing other logic.

The reading thread accumulates the data in a list that is passed to it by the class that created it. This data can then be accessed through this wrapper class without waiting for the output to complete.

```
import time
import datetime
from random import randint
import sys

def measure_distance():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return randint(10,15)

while True:
    distance = measure_distance()
    print ("%s,%s" % (datetime.datetime.now(),distance))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```